# Python--A better way to rewrite the function code?

Tags: python

use global variable is easy to present the whole design. but global variable has some constraint. It can not function as in the whole class.

It would be better to write a choice function in the code.

It will be def choice in the class.

Now the choice variable is outside the class.

Rewrite the code into the class.

the output is

```
 Enter choice: 1 for full_name, 2 for age, 3 for bmi, 4 for analysis
 user enter 1 
 output: Alex L. 
 user enter 2 
 output:28 
 user enter 3
 ouput:0.0024691358024691358 
 user enter 4 
 output:You need to eat more.
```

**do not use global variable and use the "def choice:" to rewrite it.**

```
import datetime

choice=input('Enter choice: 1 for full_name, 2 for age, 3 for bmi, 4 for analysis')
choice=int(choice)
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, birthday_year, address, telephone, email):
      self.name = name
      self.birthday_year = birthday_year
      self.address= address
      self.telephone = telephone
      self.email = email

  def full_name(self,surname,firstname):
      self.surname = surname
      self.firstname = firstname
      return self.firstname+" "+self.surname

  def age(self,birthday_year):
      self.birthday_year=birthday_year
      currentyear= datetime.datetime.now().year
      age = currentyear - self.birthday_year
      return age

  def bmi(self,weight,height):
      self.weight= weight
      self.height = height
      result= self.weight / (self.height**2)
      return result

  def analysis(self,result):
      self.result=result
      if result < 18.5:
         print ("You need to eat more.")
      elif result > 25:
         print ("Try to care yourself.")
      else:
         print ("You are a healthy person.")


def main():

    s= Person ("Alex",1990,"Wonderland",2345678,"aa@smail.com")
    if choice== 1:
       a = s.full_name("L.", "Alex")
       print(a)
    elif choice==2:
       b = s.age(1990)
       print(b)
    elif choice==3:
       c = s.bmi(80, 180)
       print(c)
    elif choice ==4:
       c = s.bmi(80, 180)
       d = s.analysis(c)
       print(d)
    else:
       print("invaild entry")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This site isn't for people to write stuff for you... This is a Q&A site

Comment: I just want to see some amazing coding style. different solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately this question is too broad, and may generate lots of never-ending meaningless posts. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary and functions, which are needed to be run in each select. Here is a sample code. You will need to modify this code to serve your needs.

```
def one():
    return "Alex L"


def two():
    return "28"


def three():
    return "0.0024691358024691358"


def four():
    return "You need to eat more"


def choice(argument):
    switcher = {
        1: one,
        2: two,
        3: three,
        4: four,
    }
# Get the function from switcher dictionary
    func = switcher.get(argument, lambda: "Invalid choice")
# Execute the function
    print(func())


choice(1)
choice(2)
choice(3)
choice(4)
```